# How can I remove all my possible broken packages or duplicate sources at Ubuntu?

Tags: package-management, dpkg

I am looking to remove all possible broken packages because yesterday I tried to download VM and also lutris, but now it is not working. How can I improve it?

I did this check:

```
sudo apt-get check
```

And:

```
W: Target Packages (contrib/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:63 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:2
W: Target Packages (contrib/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:63 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:2
W: Target Translations (contrib/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:63 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:2
W: Target Translations (contrib/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:63 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:2
W: Target DEP-11 (contrib/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:63 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:2
W: Target DEP-11 (contrib/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:63 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:2
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (contrib/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:63 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:2
W: Target DEP-11-icons (contrib/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:63 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:2
W: Target DEP-11-icons-hidpi (contrib/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:63 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:2
W: Target CNF (contrib/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:63 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:2
W: Target CNF (contrib/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:63 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:2
```

I do not know what they mean.

Comment: If you have broken packages you have to reinstall them before removing. And while at that you should clean-up your software sources.

Answer (score 0):

Use this script :

```
 #!/bin/bash 
 # Detect os codename 
 codename=$(awk '/UBUNTU_CODENAME=/' /etc/os-release | sed 's/UBUNTU_CODENAME=//' | sed 's/[.]0/./') 
  
 # Replace sources.list   
 text="deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ $codename main universe restricted multiverse 
 deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ $codename main universe restricted multiverse 
 deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $codename-security main universe restricted multiverse 
 deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $codename-security main universe restricted multiverse 
 deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ $codename-updates main universe restricted multiverse 
 deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ $codename-updates main universe restricted multiverse" 
  
 sudo echo "$text" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list 
  
 # Start upgrade 
 sudo apt update 
 sudo apt install -f 
 sudo apt upgrade 
 sudo apt dist-upgrade 
 sudo apt autoremove --purge
```